# My project won't build because it can't resolve references to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My project won't build because it can't resolve references to

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client
```

and many other similar libraries for instance:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.ExploratoryTesting.Common
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Activities.Common
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.Themes
```

How do I resolve this?  Do I have to install TFS client?  I couldn't find a way to install TFS client.  I used package manager in my VS to install microsoft.teamfoundationserver.client.15.112.1 but that did not solve all these issues.

test environment: VS 2015
Target framework: .Net 4.5.1

Comment: Have you installed the tfs 2015 power tools?

Comment: Yes, I installed both Visual Studio 2015 Power Tools as well as TFS 2015 Power Toools, but the problem persists